# SQLite- Insert using foreign key - Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am basically having issues with the syntax and can't find much information anywhere. 
I have two tables. Category_tb and Information_tb.

Category_tb
Has column of category_name(text).
Information_tb
Has title(text) and category_id(INTEGER)

I am not using the foreign key I am using ROWID of Category_tb.
Here are the SQL quires. Basically I am having a problem with the insertion of data into Information_tb using Category_tb.ROWID as a foreign key.

```
title = 'Some title'
categories = 'Crime'
self.curr.execute("""
                    insert into information_tb values (?,?)""",(
                        [title],
                        ["""select ROWID from Category_tb where Category_tb.category_name = [categories] """]
                        ))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values clause of the insert statement should be column names. It can't contain a select statement. However, you can specify the values with a select statement.

Try this:

```
self.curr.execute("insert into information_tb (title, category_id) select ?, ROWID from Category_tb where Category_tb.category_name = ?",
      (title, categories))
```

Remember to commit afterward to save the changes.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but I got a general idea. I wanted to get the ROWID of the category the that matched categories and inserted that ID into category_id of information_tb.
I worte this quries but still getting an error, please take a look at it.

  self.curr.execute("""
   insert into information_tb (title, category_id) Values (?,select ROWID from category where category.category = ?)"""
   ,(title, categories[0]))

Getting an error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "select": syntax error"

Comment: @ahsanmukhtar You don't need `values (...`. Please copy the code I've given.

Comment: I did I got this SQLite error sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @ahsanmukhtar You have to enclose the values in parentheses: `(title, categories)`. The brackets are important.